# How is gain margin defined for this control system?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, stability, bode-plot, phase-margin

Lets say there is a system

H(s) = 3/s

which I want to control with a controller

G(s) = Kp·(1+10/s)

[image]

The Bode diagram of the open loop G(s)H(s) with Kp=1 is:

[image]

At the transit frequency the phase is about -150°, which gives a phase margin of 30°.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Decreasing K makes the phase reserve smaller and ringing is increased:

[image]

Q1: I understand this behavior, but usually it is said that by increasing Kp the system gets more unstable, but here the opposite is the case. So why is there a "discrepancy"?

Q2: (This is the main question): How is gain margin defined here? In my opinion, GM is infinite, because gain can be increased infinitely without making the system unstable.

EDIT:
LTSpice simulation of the same system

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please draw the system diagram so there is zero ambiguity on what the graphs represent.

Comment: What do you mean? The Bode Plot above? It is G(s)H(s) with KP=1. 
"The bode diagram of the open loop G(s)H(s) with KP=1 is: ..."
The other graphs are not really relevant, but they are the responses to a unit step at the reference input of the control system.

Comment: I added the system diagram above

Comment: The loop gain should be -GH instead of +GH as you have assumed.  Everything will be fine then. Just replot it in MATLAB.

Comment: what do you mean? Given H and G, the transfer function of the closed loop is GH/(1+GH). Ans this is, what I have plotted.

Comment: No, you have plotted GH in figure 1. The loop gain that you have plotted should be -GH, and the phase response of the loop gain should decrease with frequency.

Comment: The term "open loop gain" might be defined differently among textbooks (maybe the summation point is then defined with a plus instead of a minus), but in all books I studied so far, loop gain is G*H for the example above. About this I'm absolutely sure. Do you have a link where your point of view is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of the transfer functions gives (as shown in the diagram) a phase shift of 180° at very low frequencies (including DC). This results from the unrealistic assumption of ideal integrators.
That means: With a minus sign at the summing junction, we have a problem (positive feedback for DC - no operational point).

The circuit works only with (at least) one real integrating function. Only in this case, we can evaluate the stability properties of the closed loop.

Independent on this, the loop gain for a realistic second-order circuit can never reach a phase shift of 180° at a finite frequency.

Comment: Are you sure the closed loop system is unstable? The closed loop transfer function for Kp=1 is (0.03 s^3 + 0.3 s^2)/(0.01 s^4 + 0.03 s^3 + 0.3 s^2) and this is a stable system, as you can see from the step response above. Where do you see a problem with operational point? The pole at s=0 is cancelled out. If you simulate this with LTSpice there is no problem and you get exactly the same signal as Matlab gives you.

Comment: @MichaelW It looks like you have an extra \$s\$ in there, because I get \$GH/(1+GH)=3K_p(s+10)/(s^2+3K_ps+30K_p)\$ (given your first two transfer functions).

Comment: this is the same

Comment: @MichaelW Which sign do you assume at the summing junction? Can you always trust simulation results - in particular, when the gain of a block approaches infinity? As soon as  it automatically assumes any finite (large) number we have a lowpass and not an ideal integrator function. My simulation results for the closed loop are identical to the diagram as shown above - however, assuming a lowpass function with a cutoff at 100µHz (mikro!). Hence, we have 180deg phase shift at the summing junction for DC.

Comment: @LvW We are discussing things now, which are not really covering my question... 
Whatever, regardless whether the integrator is realized as ideal or with a low-pass, a simulation carried out with LTSpice (see EDIT in my question) gives the same result (assuming sufficient high time constant of the low-pass in the integrator). Problems would arise, if there are any intermediate infinite signals within the circuit, but this is not the case and so I would trust.

Comment: @LvW Systems with higher degree of denominator as nominator can be physically realized - this is the case here.
When you say, that a closed system would be unstable when there is a 180° phase at f=0 then many books about control theory would be in need to be re-written. 

For example in one of my textbooks a model system S=1/(s*(s+1)^3) is controlled with a PI =  kp*(1+1/(s*Tn)) and the optimization of such controller is discussed in much detail. Here gain we have 180° at f=0 in the open loop Bode. Many other examples exist. So I cannot follow, why it should be "invalid" to consider it.

Comment: MichaelW - sorry, there is a typing error in my comment above (last line). Of course, for a stable bias point the phase shift at the summing junction must be zero deg - as provided by REAL integrators (lowpass). Only in this case we have negative DC feedback. Fortunately, books have not to be rewritten.

Comment: What do you mean in detail? The Phase shift of the open loop (not regarding the minus at the summation) *IS* 180° in my example. Nevertheless the transfer function of the closed system has 0dB for f-->0 and the controller works perfectly. Otherwise you would never be able to control an I System (e.g. water level control...) with a PI-controller.

Comment: I agree - from the pure mathematical point of view, the phase shift of both blocks together is 180 deg (at very low frequencies, including DC).  So - what happens when the loop is closed (with a minus sign at the summing point)? The total phase shift is 360 (zero) deg, is it not? So we have positive feedback - or not? Therefore, I expect problems (instability). However, simulation results show a stable system. What is your explanation?

Comment: we have positive feedback, but there is an additional  zero at f=0 ! You see from the simulation that nothing strange happens and that there is a final operating point: The controller has output zero at the end.

Comment: Exactly this was my point! According to the stability criterion the closed-loop cannot be stable (positive feedback at f=0). But this is pure theory! In reality we have no ideal integrators with infinite gain at f=0. And that´s what the simulation programs do - they assume a finite gain - otherwise they could not show the results above. That`s all I wanted to make clear - nothing else!

Comment: MichaelW - only now I have checked your LT simulation in detail! Are you aware that the circuits named "ideal" integrators are, of course, NOT IDEAL ? The opamp models have a finite gain and the "ideal" integrators are in fact lowpass stages. So - no surprise that the closed-loop is stable. But you have not correctly simulated the functions of the task description. Do you agree?

Comment: To be honest: no I do not agree: There would be no change in the simulation using ideal op-amps. And moreover, when you skip op-amps at all and instead use mathematical ideal blocks, the simulation would give the same result. Yes - in reality there is no "ideal" integrator, but nevertheless it makes sense to use those abstract and ideal building blocks (like I-controller, PID-controller, ...) to derive valid statements about stability - this is what theory of linear systems is about. And the system I talk about is stable in the loop - regardless whether ideal or non-ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, this discussion, albeit interesting,  does not cover my question: What does gain margin mean in general, when we consider systems like the one I put into discussion. In other words: Is it possible, that gain-margin is not defined at all for particular systems like the one above?

Comment: I think the answer to your last question is obvious: Gain margin is the additional gain that  must be inserted into the feedback loop to bring the closed loop to the stability limit. But there are systems that cannot fulfill the phase condition for instability (at least 3rd order). In this case we cannot define any gain margin because any additional gain within the loop cannot meet the criterion for instability.

Comment: I like to comment your statements regarding "abstract ideal building blocks" instead of opamp-based realizations. I have performed such simulations (using VISSIM) - and the closed-loop shows a stable behaviour. Is this a surprise? No, of course not - because these programs are pure mathematical models and simulate the closed-loop according to GH/(1+GH). But in real life using real active components the circuits are forced to have a fixed and stable DC bias point - but all these mathematical programs (like Wolfram alpha and VISSIM) are not required to perform this initial step.

Comment: Of course, in practice I would finally end up  with a non-ideal system. Nevertheless, the idealized system behind it (model in mind) is also stable and gives practically the same result. Non-ideal systems can only deviate from their ideal counterparts if some intrinsic state variables are subject to system limits -  but no limit is reached in the simulation above! The fact that a control system is never ideal in practice does not automatically imply that the underlying theoretical model is un-stable. But, you're trying to convince me of that...The system we talk about is stable also in theory.

Comment: **In this case we cannot define any gain margin because any additional gain within the loop cannot meet the criterion for instability.**

This is the answer to my question. It would mean that the term "gain margin" is simply not applicable to the system above. I've suspected that all along but was not sure: Up to now gain margin and phase margin were closely related to me and constituted just two different but closely related points of view in terms of stability. But this example shows, that I can have phase margin well defined although gain margin gives no sense.

Comment: Your sentence "The system we talk about is stable also in theory" is somewhat misleading. How can a non-realizable system be stable? This is because we cannot realize the given functions in practice. Each real integrator is a lowpass with a (hopefully) very low cut-off frequency. Of course, each engineer knows this limitation - and he converts an idealized block H(s)=A/s automatically into H(s)=A/(1+sT).

Comment: The question is answered.
But according to your considerations, even a simple PI controller cannot be implemented in practice. Nevertheless, the literature is full of examples with PI controllers. The fact, that an ideal PI controller is not realizable perfectly  does not mean that the term is useless per se. From theory of LTI systems the above theoretical system is stable without any doubts, and additionally I'm convinced, that the realization using the Op-Amps above is feasible too, provided we chose a proper op-amp. So where is the problem for you in particular regarding stability?

Comment: I know what you mean.  And I can agree. However, it may be that I am thinking too much about a practical realization. I come from practice and something resists in me to investigate the behavior of non-realizable blocks. Let`s end this discussion. Thanks and bye.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: I understand this behavior, but usually it is said that by increasing Kp the system gets more unstable, but here the opposite is the case. So why is there a "discrepancy"?

For systems with a low pass characteristic this is generally true. However, for an arbitrary type of system you cannot generalize it like this. Stability depends on both phase and magnitude, and Kp only influences the magnitude.

> Q2: (This is the main question): How is gain margin defined here? In my opinion, GM is infinite, because gain can be increased infinitely without making the system unstable.

Gain margin is defined as the amount of gain (amplification) needed to bring your system into instability. For your system \$H(s) = \frac{3}{s} \$ the gain margin is infinite because the critical point (0dB magnitude and -\$180^\circ\$ phase) is never reached.

[image]

I don't see why you intend to use an integrator in your control loop. Here is the step response with a Kp = 10 in the forward branch, and it looks pretty fast.

```
s = tf('s');
H = 3/s;
Kp = 10;
Hcl = feedback(H*Kp,1);
step(Hcl)
```

[image]

Comment: The question goes back to a school example, which was given by a teacher for exactly the same system: It was asked how to chose Kp the PI controller to achieve a given gain margin. Apparently he made a mistake here, because in this case there is no gain margin defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: ...  usually it is said that by increasing Kp the system gets more unstable, but here the opposite is the case.

Yes, because there is a "little" problem.

A "differentiator" is included in the "G" function ...